# IPMI throwing "Reservation Canceled or Invalid Reservation ID" during GetSDR command

Tags: ipmitool, ipmi, ipmiutil

Following is the sequence in my code:
1. GetSdrRepositoryInfo
2. ReserveSdrRepository
3. GetSdr command in iteration where every GetSDR command response gives next record ID to be inquired.

However, GetSDR command in some server and for some record IDs throws "Reservation Canceled or Invalid Reservation ID". Please help in how to overcome this exception and what should be the next step.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently "wrong" with getting an "Reservation Canceled" or "Invalid Reservation ID" error.  As other software on the system may be using the SDR, it is possible for the service processor to return such an error.  You should simply retrieve a new reservation id and retry the Get SDR request.

If you are getting the error repeatedly on the same record ID, then there is likely a bug/error with your motherboard.  You should contact the vendor to fix their firmware.